# Issue when highlighting error message upon pressing the "Submit" button without selecting a date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, react-hook-form

I am experiencing an issue in my web application. When I press the "Submit" button without selecting a date, the error message displays correctly. However, I have noticed that the text does not highlight in red as it should. Additionally, I intend for the borders to also appear in red. Although I have tried various approaches, I have been unable to achieve this effect without resorting to external CSS styles. Is there any suggestion or solution to achieve this effect without the need for additional CSS? I appreciate any guidance you can provide on this matter.

This is how my component appeared:

[image]

I wish it that way

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { LocalizationProvider, DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

const DateComponent = () => {
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("Formulario enviado:", data);
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", marginTop: "25px" }}
    >
      <Box width={300}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="selectedDate"
          defaultValue={null}
          rules={{ required: true }} // Add the required property here
          render={({ field }) => (
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
              <DatePicker
                label="Date"
                {...field}
                slotProps={{
                  textField: {
                    helperText: errors.selectedDate ? "Campo requerido" : "",
                  },
                }}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
          )}
        />

        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
         Submit
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </form>
  );
};

export default DateComponent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `error` prop for `textField` inside `slotProps`.

```
<DatePicker
   label="Date"
   {...field}
   slotProps={{
     textField: {
       helperText: errors.selectedDate ? "Campo requerido" : "",
       error: !!errors.selectedDate
     },
    }}
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

inside the **TextField**
**textField** is an object that contains two properties: helperText and error. These properties are used to customize the appearance and behavior of the text field associated with the DatePicker. Let's look at each property:

error:

This property is typically used to indicate whether there is an error in the input field.

This helps to visually highlight the input field when there is an error.

**helperText**
This property is likely used to display a helper or error message beneath the text field.
and also This helps provide feedback to the user about the input requirements.

```
<DatePicker
      label="Date"
      {...field}
      slotProps={{
      textField: {
           helperText: errors.selectedDate ? "Data is Required" : "",
           error: errors.selectedDate ? true : false
          },
       }}
    />
```